# How do I delete files and folders in sub-directories but skip delete for certain file names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm looking for a way to delete files in sub-directories no matter the depth but also keep an exclusion list of files not to delete.

exclude list = [my.file]

*given folder structure (folders end with /)*

```
one/
  my.file
  two/
    x.x
    x.x
    xxx/
      xx
      my.file
    xxxx/
      xx
```

*after delete (every file that is not in the exclude list gets deleted, and the folder gets deleted if there are no children)*

```
one/
  my.file
  two/
    xxx/
      my.file
```

I've been using this so far but it doesn't go below the first level

```
    inside(directory) do
        FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob('*').reject { |f| whitelist.include?(f) }
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In comments you say you don't want to recursively delete, you want to *selectively* delete, and it sounds like you want to only remove those directories that are missing .gitignore files. If so, please update your question to contain the real requirements. As is your question doesn't match what you say you're asking for, which is misleading and frustrating to those trying to help you.

Comment: My bad, yes sorry although I left the reject call in the command which makes it a bit clearer. I will update.

Comment: Something to think about is whether to use `Dir.glob('**/*')` or take advantage of the [`Find.find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) method. On a complex directory structure, the first can take a very long time to run as it descends through it building the array of entries, which are then held in memory. Using `Find.find` will immediately start processing and will recursively descend, handing you the directory and file names it encounters one-by-one. It's much more efficient but a little bit more complex to write. I recommend using `Find.find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FilUtils [remove_dir](http://require%20%22fileutils%22%20FileUtils.remove_dir(%22test%22)) removes recursively.

```
require "fileutils"
FileUtils.remove_dir("the_dir")
```

No weakhearted whitelists though - everything disappears.

Comment: How can I make it ignore all the .gitignore files in the recursive delete?

Comment: I don't think that is possible using `remove_dir` in  a reasonable way. But Git is a powerful tool and a popular tag at SO, so maybe a rephrased, more Git-oriented question is successful .

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
inside(directory) do
    FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob('**/*').reject { |f| whitelist.include?(File.basename(f)) }
end
```

Although that may delete directories as well. In which case use `File.directory?(f)` as part of the reject criteria.